# How to copy the output of a command to nano editor

Tags: putty, nano

I am following a guide to setup WordPress. One of the steps instructs to copy the values of `https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/` to a section in `wp-config.php`. I can connect via PuTTY only remotely to this server and I am using the `nano` editor. The question is how to do this without typing each individual character into the `wp-config.php`.

On an MS-DOS Windows console you can mark the text and then copy it. PuTTY has the option to copy everything to clipboard, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (paste) does not work, saying: "*cut buffer is empty*".

Comment: Why not use wget or curl to just download the content straight into the file?

Comment: this is the command (curl -s https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/) I can see the output as they say in the tutorial but the next step is to copy it to the wp-config that I do not how  how to do it, I open nano but nothing can be pasted to nano editor with sudo access.

Comment: `curl -s https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt >> wp-config.php` and then edit it to move around the salt as needed

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> shortcut is to paste text that was copied (or cut) from within nano. You will want to use one of these:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>

That’ll do what you’re looking for

Comment: thank very much, 'Shift + Insert' worked.

Comment: What’s a mouse? Haven’t used one in 15+ years 